# Unfair coin vs Random algorithm

Tags: random

I had bought an unfair coin. The probability of getting a tail is 75% `P(T) = 3/4` and the probability of getting a head is 25% `P(H) = 1/4`

I decided to do the following experiment: I programmed a computer to generate a **random boolean**.

TRUE means Head and FALSE means Tails

. Then I toss the coin and I check if the result is the same as the computer random guess.

```
var random_boolean = Math.random() >= 0.5;
if (random_boolean) {
    save(Heads_count++)
    console.log('I guess: HEAD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
} else {
   save(Tails_count++)
    console.log('I guess: TAIL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
}
```

I call it **SUCCESS** if the two results match. It repeat the same experience several time (N) and I count the number of success.

Weirdly, I get a success rate tending toward **50%** . Why is that? Is it normal assuming that the computer generate a fair random boolean and knowing that the coin is unfair?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're flipping a weighted coin and comparing it to guesses based on code assuming a fair weight for each side. Why not write code that does both, run through it a million or so times and compare those. It might not be correct (an answer below does disagree) but my instinct tells me you shouldn't get 50% success.

Comment: Strike that, I have just had a look and the answer below convinces me mathematically, however much my instinct dislikes it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is normal and in fact doesn't depend on your coin at all. Let us look at two independent random variables with range $\{0,1\}$: $X$ represents your toss, $Y$ represents your computer's guess. Let $P(X = 0) = p$ - the probability of your toss to be '$0$'. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X = Y) &= P(X = Y = 0 \cup X = Y = 1) \\
&= P(X=0) P(Y=0) + P(X=1)P(Y=1) \\
&= p \cdot 0.5 + (1-p) \cdot 0.5 \\
&= 0.5
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: you mentioned: "It doesn't depend on your coin at all". Does this mean that whether the coin is totally random or totally arranged (like following a function, or a deterministic sequence), it doesn't matter, the success of guessing its value through random algorithm will always be 50%?

Comment: What I meant is that it doesn't depend on the value of $p$ above.

Comment: Omg, this is true.